# Getting same results from Mapping toolbox of MATLAB as ArcMap?

Tags: coordinate-system, matlab-mapping-toolbox

I am newbie in GEO. I have a point [lat,lon] = [-77.5100 , 166.4000]. I want to find its projection based on equidistant Azimuthal projection method. When I use ArcMap 10.3.1 (with default parameters), I receive [x,y]=[1877942.02210000 , 3755681.82180000]. however, when I use MATLAB (origin set to [0,0]), I receive [x,y]=[ 0.0927, -1.7802]. How can I tune MATLAB to produce the same result of ArcMap.

Details:
MATLAB code:

```
mstruct = defaultm('eqdazim');
mstruct.origin = [0 0];
mstruct = defaultm(mstruct);
[x,y]=mfwdtran(mstruct,-77.51,166.4)  % produces [0.092723,-1.7802]
```

ArcMap 10.3.1 code (default parameters, arcPy code)

```
    arcpy.Project_management("point.txt","PROJECT", "GEOGCS['GCS_Sphere',DATUM['D_Sphere',SPHEROID['Sphere',6371000.0,0.0]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Azimuthal_Equidistant'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',0.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',0.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',0.0],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]")
```

Comment: My guess is that Matlab is using a sphere of R=1.0 or something similar.

Comment: I used also mstruct.scale = 6371000;  but the same result.